# Automatic authentication with VSCode Remote Tunnel on a cluster compute node

Tags: visual-studio-code, cluster-computing, slurm, ssh-tunnel, vscode-remote

I came across [this helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58532641/how-can-i-ensure-vs-code-remote-ssh-server-runs-on-a-compute-node-of-our-cluster) on VSCode Remote Tunnel on a cluster compute node.
Is there a way to also automate the authentication (similar to ssh-key) such that one doesn't need to follow the activation code procedure every time he is reassigned a new compute node (by some job scheduler)?

Currently, every time my compute node allocation expires I have to request it anew, and also follow the manual reactivation of the tunnel with the activation code on GitHub.